# Adding a GUI to a Video-playing program (in Processing using Java)

Tags: java, user-interface, video, processing

I have to make a program that can both play and alter a video file. I've worked out how to play the video file, but I can't work out how to extend the window of the program to build a GUI while keeping the video playing with the same dimensions. Here is my code thus far if this is helpful:

```
import processing.video.*;
Movie myMovie;

void setup() {
  myMovie = new Movie(this, "hollywood_test.mp4");
  surface.setResizable(true);
  surface.setSize(640,360);
  background(0);
  myMovie.loop();
  tint(255,200,200);
  myMovie.play();
}

void draw() {
  image(myMovie,0,0,width,height);
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}
```

How  can I format the code so that I can play the video with the same dimensions, while adding space for a GUI?

Comment: The current dimensions of the video is "the whole window", is that what you had in mind? Please elaborate a little bit about what you want to implement as GUI, what it looks, where it's located, etc...

Comment: Ah, that's really helpful - thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

As @laancelot said, you are setting the size of the movie to `width` and `height`.
you can simply set the `width` and `height` of the `image()` to what you currently have the `size()` set to (ie 640x360).

```
image(myMovie, 0, 0, 640, 360);
```

then set the `size()` to be 100 pixels taller

```
size(640, 460);
```

and now you have 100 pixels of empty space below the movie to add a GUI. You can play with the value however you like, but the main idea is to keep the `image()`'s with and height smaller than `size()`.